# oracle sql parent child with for multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a users table having two columns for Approval Hierarchy , Table structure is like below

```
User_ID    Submit_to  Approve_to
1          2          3
2          4          5
3          6          2
4          2          3
5          1          0
```

Data is just For example `0` Mention no Approver :
Submit to and Approve to both will be Approvers

I need a Query which can give the Approves details in sequence that who will be next approver for entry user have created .

Comment: Can't you show us the expected result too.

Answer (score 0):

Using CONNECT BY, you can connect the parent/child relationship within a table.  The query below will show the approval path for each user.

#### Query

```
WITH
    d (user_id, submit_to, approve_to)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 4, 5 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 6, 2 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 2, 3 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5, 1, 0 FROM DUAL)
    SELECT d.user_id, LTRIM (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (user_id, '<'), '<') AS approval_path
      FROM d
START WITH approve_to = 0
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR user_id = approve_to
  ORDER BY user_id;
```

#### Result

In the APPROVAL_PATH column, the left most number is the USER_ID giving final approval and the right most number is the USER_ID initially submitting whatever needs to be approved.

```
USER_ID | APPROVAL_PATH
-----------------------
      1 | 5<2<3<1
      2 | 5<2
      3 | 5<2<3
      4 | 5<2<3<4
      5 | 5
```